# AADSTS50146 error when attempting to retrieve Oauth access_token

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, client, credentials

Looking for some AzureAD help with this error -

> "error": "invalid_request", "error_description": "AADSTS50146: This
>   application is required to be configured with an application-specific
>   signing key.\r\nTrace ID:
>   6fb978c1-0d74-478c-991c-3ad48ca65f00\r\nCorrelation ID:
>   81c05804-175c-456b-8d45-d5365818b599\r\nTimestamp: 2019-12-17
>   19:28:29Z",

I get the error above in one AzureAD env. when trying to do a OAuth2.0 token request. I have another test AzureAD where the same request works fine.

Doing a POST to https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token with clientId, clientSecret and grant_type=client_credentials.

Found this via google - https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/5394 but wanted to understand how does one go about configuring the "scope" parameter in AzureAD.

Comment: Any update for this issue?

Answer (score 11):

You probably have additional/mapped claims.

If you do not want to bother with creating application-specific signing keys,
you need to set `"acceptMappedClaims": true` in the manifest.
Setting `"accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2` can also help.

Make sure to check the manifest of both the client and the target API (resource server/audience).

- When requesting an access token with mapped claims, the `acceptMappedClaims` of the target API needs to be `true`.
- When requesting an id token with mapped claims, the `acceptMappedClaims` of the client needs to be `true`.

When requesting both, id token and access token (as is common), and both tokens include additional claims, both app registrations need to have `acceptMappedClaims` set.

*Note*: as per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/jwt-claims-customization#security-considerations), only use `acceptMappedClaims` on single-tenant apps. For multi-tenant apps, you want to use app-specific signing keys.

Comment: Q: What if you want to create application-specific signing keys? How to proceed?

Comment: This is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/jwt-claims-customization#configure-a-custom-signing-key. It seems there is currently no UI, you have to make HTTP requests to add signing keys.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need both

```
"acceptMappedClaims": true,
```

and

```
"allowPublicClient": true,
```

in your app's manifest.

Answer (score -1):

The api permissions in Azure AD portal is the value of scope.

[image]

You can also expose an API, then you can add your own scope.

[image]